# Join twice on same table with different conditions and no PK / FK relations

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have the following tables:

1. **agencies**: | code |
2. **commissions**: | registered_at | action | origin | destination | commission |

I need to SUM(commissions.commission) for the following conditions

1. agencies.code = commissions.origin HAVING commissions.action = "collection"
2. agencies.code = commissions.destination HAVING commissions.action = "delivery"

```
WHERE Date(commissions.registered_at) between '2023-01-01 00:00:00' and '2023-01-31 23:59:59'  
Group By agencies.code
```

As you can see, these 2 tables have no PK / FK relations.
They are related by the destination / origin and the action being queried.

I tried to make a double Left Join on commissions, but that seems to call the second join for the number of records from the first join. I also don't see how I can make it work with IF conditions inside SELECT, as the conditions to join the tables are different.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [Help me write this query in SQL](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `registered_at` is indexed (with `registered_at` as the first column ot only column) in the `commissions` table, then there is a better way to expression the WHERE clauses on `registered_at`.

This `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE DATE(registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
```

will trigger a table scan for sure because of the [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function on the left side.

Please change

```
WHERE DATE(registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
```

to

```
  WHERE registered_at >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND registered_at <= '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
```

This will definitely change the EXPLAIN plan to hopefully use the index.

So the query should look like this

```
SELECT agencies.code, 
       COALESCE(collections.collections, 0) as collections,
       COALESCE(deliveries.deliveries, 0) as deliveries
FROM agencies
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT origin as code, 
         SUM(IF(action = 'collection', commission, 0)) as collections,
         SUM(IF(action = 'delivery', commission, 0)) as deliveries
  FROM commissions
  WHERE registered_at >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND registered_at <= '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY origin
) collections ON agencies.code = collections.code
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT destination as code, 
         SUM(IF(action = 'collection', commission, 0)) as collections,
         SUM(IF(action = 'delivery', commission, 0)) as deliveries
  FROM commissions
  WHERE registered_at >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND registered_at <= '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY destination
) deliveries ON agencies.code = deliveries.code;
```

If there is no `registered_at` index in the `commissions` table, then create one

```
ALTER TABLE commissions
    ADD INDEX covering_index (registered_at,action,commission)
   ,ALGORITHM=INPLACE
   ,LOCK=NONE
;
```

This will create short index scans and not touch the table.

Comment: This seems a more complete answer than my own. Also thank you for alternative suggestion instead of BETWEEN. Did not know.

Answer (score 1):

#### EDIT

**Correct** answer is:

```
SELECT agencies.code, 
       COALESCE(collections.collections, 0) as collections,
       COALESCE(deliveries.deliveries, 0) as deliveries
FROM agencies
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT origin as code, 
         SUM(IF(action = 'collection', commission, 0)) as collections,
         SUM(IF(action = 'delivery', commission, 0)) as deliveries
  FROM commissions
  WHERE DATE(registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY origin
) collections ON agencies.code = collections.code
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT destination as code, 
         SUM(IF(action = 'collection', commission, 0)) as collections,
         SUM(IF(action = 'delivery', commission, 0)) as deliveries
  FROM commissions
  WHERE DATE(registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY destination
) deliveries ON agencies.code = deliveries.code;
```

This seems to be the correct solution.

Previous answer - **Incorrect**:

```
SELECT agencies.code, 
       SUM(IF(commissions.action = 'collection', commissions.commission, 0)) as collections,
       SUM(IF(commissions.action = 'delivery', commissions.commission, 0)) as deliveries
FROM agencies
LEFT JOIN commissions ON agencies.code = commissions.origin OR agencies.code = commissions.destination
WHERE DATE(commissions.registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY agencies.code;
```

This seemed to be working alright at first, but all results had some added value that I did not manage to find out the cause of.

Comment: Necessary read: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: about `between` -  check [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/231007/22336) out please!

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ cool read

Answer (score 0):

(Not an "Answer", but some comments that may help clarify things:)

- You can `JOIN` tables without declaring a `FOREIGN KEY`.
- You can `JOIN` tables without declaring an `INDEX`.  (But it is likely to be slower.)
- A `FOREIGN KEY` provides (1) an `INDEX` and (2) a constraint that is checked -- to see if, during an `INSERT`, there is a corresponding row in the other table (3) a way to `CASCADE` certain things.  I repeat, it is not a prerequisite for `JOINing`.
- A "self join" is when you need the same table twice, for eaxmple

  ```
    FROM tbl AS t1
    JOIN tbl AS t2 ON t1.a = t2.b+1
  ```
- Similarly you can `JOIN` to the same table twice:

  ```
    FROM tbl
    JOIN other_table AS t2 ON tbl.a = t2.b
    JOIN other_table AS t3 ON tbl.x = t3.y
  ```
- When practical, use `WHERE` instead of `HAVING`.  Aggregates must be in `HAVING`, not `WHERE`.  If you tried to put such in `WHERE`, MySQL will spit at you.
- (minor note) I recommend instead of

  ```
    x between '2023-01-01 00:00:00' and '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
  ```

doing

```
         x >= '2023-01-01'
     AND x  < '2023-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
```

- More importantly, `Date(commissions.registered_at)` is not [*sargable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) ; all you need is just `commissions.registered_at`